# Url ( ROTA) com NOMES e não ID

Tags: asp.net, webforms, route

Como consigo alterar dinamicamente uma URL em uma busca no BD dos Id's pelo NOME para assim se tornar uma URL mais amigável (SEO).

Minha URL hoje:

http://meusistema.com.br/Achei/26/8717/1/2/3 - sendo o `26`=ESTADO, `8717`=CIDADE,`1`=BAIRRO, `2`=CATEGORIA, `3`=NEGOCIO

A URL que penso ser melhor para visualizar:

http://meusistema.com.br/Achei/sao-paulo/sao-paulo/morumbi/casa/venda

A rota no routes.MapPageRoute fica assim:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "AcheiCatNegRoute",
            "Achei/{idestado}/{idcidade}/{idbairro}/{idcategoria}/{idnegocio}",
            "~/Achei.aspx"
```

Acho que deva existir uma forma de a URL assumir o nome é não o ID sem ter que mudar a lógica do banco de dados, acredito que fazer a busca pelo ID seja mais rápido do que por uma String, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Obs.: Utilizo ainda WebForms com Asp.NET e SQL.

Comment: como você estará passando uma String no RouteData, então terá de fazer a sua busca no SQL usando strings, o que pode ser feito para amenizar a sua situação é adicionar um indice para as colunas afetadas.

Comment: Você está usando MVC? Pode descrever como é o *binding* de parâmetros entre a camada que processa a requisição e a rota?

Comment: Como está feito no Controller?

Comment: Paulo não é MVC é WebForms